# Autolayout view dropping down

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I’ve built a simple login screen layout. In a vertical direction, there is a logo at the top, followed by 2 text boxes for email and password and then a submit button.

There is an outer container which container 2 more container views, one for the logo and one for the text boxes and button.

With auto layout, I have got the layout displaying correctly in Xcode, with the logo container above the input details container. However, when I launch the app on the simulator or on a device, the logo seems to drop down over the top of the text boxes.

Xcode is telling me I am missing a constraint for containerLayout for y position or height. I’m unsure if this has any impact on the problem.

It would be extremely useful if someone could explain why the logo is dropping down. I will include an image of the constraints in place.

[image]

Comment: You didn't set height constraint for containerLayout View ,also height constraint for logoLayout, I think this is cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

As an absolute minimum, you should:

- Add **leading**, **trailing**, **bottom** and **top** constraints to the logo image view.
- Set vertical **content hugging priority** for the text fields to required (1000).
- Add **bottom** constraint for the sign in button.

You definitely use too much of center X, and equal widths, this obscures entire picture of your layout. If you want to make it simpler and more readable include the following modifications.

- Remove **center X**, **center Y** and **equal widths** from the logo image. As you will see it won't break anything but only simplify the layout.
- For both text fields, remove **center X** and **equal widths** constraints.
- For both text fields, add **leading** and **trailing** constraints to the superview
- Repeat last two points for sign in button.

If you are targeting iOS9 or higher you can use a stack view to layout text fields and buttons. Below you can find the final result. Of course, you can introduce a lot more improvements to this layout but I don't want to reinvent it here.

[image: final result preview]

**Update**

To configure bottom constraint for the logoDetailsLayout just add it as normal. Sometimes when views are not aligned as they should be Xcode gets lost. In this case, you can double-click this constraint and fix it in the attribute inspector.

This is how I configured it.

[image: content bottom constraint configuration]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just following this now. Could you expand the logoDetailLayout constraints so I can see what you used there? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember there are only leading, trailing, top and bottom to the superview. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: The constraint inside containerLayout that has logoDetailsLayout.bottom = bottom. How do I apply that one? Struggling to get that and the layout is sitting at the top. I think that's my problem there.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can find the description on the bottom of the post.